# `runtime::Error` type

Tags: runtime, frame

Is there any way to tell the `construct_runtime!` macro to build/export a top-level `Error` enum type in the same way it provides the top-level `Call` and `Event` types?

As far as I can tell the only way to decode an Error retrieved from the runtime is to use the Metadata (which is a little cumbersome), since the inner ModuleError [erases the error message](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/src/sp_runtime/lib.rs.html#485-487) - presumably to save storage.

It would be nice if it was possible to do something like this:

```rust
match dispatch_error {
    DispatchError::ModuleError(module_error) => RuntimeError::from(module_error),
    _ => // do something else
}
```

A concrete use case for this would be a client that wants to submit and watch an extrinsic, and be able to show the user a useful error message.

Pseudo-code:

```rust
// Imagine we have a top-level runtime::Error type.
fn submit_and_watch(ex: Extrinsic) -> Result<Vec<runtime::Event>, runtime::Error> {
    let ex_hash = author.submitExtrinsic(ex);
    let ex_events = get_extrinsic_events(ex_hash);

    if let Some(ex_failed) = ex_events.find(|e| matches!(e, System::ExtrinsicFailed { .. })) {
        // Can't convert to string because `dispatch_error` erases
        // the error message.
        // Retrieving the error message currently requires (i think?)
        // parsing the metadata.
        // If we had a top-level Error type with associated conversion
        // traits, we could do it like this:
        Err(runtime::Error::from(ex_failed.dispatch_error))
    } else {
        Ok(ex_events)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to tell the construct_runtime! macro to build/export a top-level Error enum type in the same way it provides the top-level Call and Event types?

No that is not possible.

You also don't have included any reasoning on why you need this, otherwise I could maybe have given an answer with more content.

Comment: I've edited the question to add a specific use case.

But I would also argue it's just generally a little unintuitive that FRAME aggregates the pallet::Call and the pallet::Event, but not the pallet::Error. (Given that the calls, events, and errors are all very much linked, ie. a call can emit events and return errors).

Answer (score 0):

So, why not use [`DispatchError`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/dispatch/enum.DispatchError.html)?

I think this could provide enough information for users.

Comment: Sorry - should have been clearer - DispatchError erases the error message when it's encoded.

Comment: (see: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/src/sp_runtime/lib.rs.html#485-487)

Comment: (Have edited the question to make this clearer)

Comment: Interesting. For me, module index + error index is enough. PolkadotApps also return the error name only (which was indexed by the module index + error index). But yes, I think I don't have any better solutions.

Comment: It's enough, but my point is it could be *much* easier. The PolkaJs does it (I think) is by parsing the metadata. Contrast this with the `Event` type, which doesn't require this.